# I want to change text 'Hello' to green after 1 hour time interval red to after 2 hour time interval using angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created countdown time ticker using angular 5 I want to change text 'HELLO' in every 1 hr interval till 2 hr from start time like after 1st hour interval text color change to green and after 2nd hr it should change to Red.
there is one more problem currently when I am giving end date 19/12/2018 then after midnight 12 am negative time is showing in timer for same date that is 19/12/2018.

please find below link for my code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d1fqg5?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftime-ticker.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the negative value is due to the time during the input you are not giving the time along with date

```
<timer enddate="' 12/19/2018'"></timer>
```

the problem with the above format is it will conciser it as 12/19/2018 00:00:00 if  today is also 12/19/2018 as per your logic

```
this._diff = Date.parse(this.enddate) - Date.parse(new Date().toString());
```

it will be 12/19/2018 00:00:00 - 12/19/2018 01:23:11

```
//new Date() also has time
```

so the difference is negative

**as for styling** 
use

```
  <h1 [ngStyle]="{'color':_hours>=2?'green':'red'}">Hello</h1>
```

Comment: how to pass enddate='12/19/2018 00:00:00'

Comment: I want to do date condition like if  enddate= '12/20/2018 12:10:10' then after 1 hour that is 01:10:10 the text colour should be changeto green  and after two hour that is 02:10:10 text colour should be changed to red

Comment: i highly recommend using moment.js module for dealing with dates [link](https://momentjs.com/docs/) for giving the date with time `new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');` or `new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');` check [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)